# Find the limit of an infinite product related to the alternating harmonic convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, infinite-product, harmonic-numbers

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^x \left(1+\frac1{xn(2n-1)}\right)^x=4
$$
I know this equals 4 because I derived this equation from the alternating harmonic series:

$1-\frac1{2} +\frac1{3} -\frac1{4} + \frac1{5}- \cdots=\ln2$

I could add a picture of my work but basically that series, s, yields this equation:
$$
e^{2s}={\prod_{n=1}^\infty}e^{\frac1{2n^2-n}} 
$$

Then, we represent e using the limit definition:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac x{n}\right)^n=e^x$$

The question is, how do we work out that infinite product that we know is equal to 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many problems with infinite products, take the logarithm. Then,
$$ \log(P) = \log\Big(\prod_{n=1}^x \big(1+\frac{1}{x\,n(2n-1)}\big)^x \Big)
=x\sum_{n=1}^x  \log\big(1+\frac{1}{x\,n(2n-1)} \big)$$
$$ = x\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{x\,n(2n-1)} -x \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{ 2(x\,n(2n-1))^2} + ...$$
where the expansion for the logarithm $\log(1+z) = z -z^2/2+...$ has been used.
The second sum goes to 0 as it has a 1/x factor.  Thus, all that is left is to 
prove a formula that is pretty standard fare,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n-1)} = \log{4} . $$

Comment: I see that all the terms in the logarithm expansion, except for the first one, go to zero but it would be 1/ 2(xn(2n-1))^2 +... right?

Comment: Machine, you are correct.  I've fixed typo.

Comment: Your log 4 sum is the power of e in the original infinite product before the limits.